# Ubuntu Linux Parted Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/sde

Tags: parted

I have created and attached an disk to VMware VM and trying to create a partition on the disk using parted Utility.but got the errors Input/output error during write on /dev/sde.If we do the fdisk -l ,it showing me the newly attached disk,If we create a partition using fdisk it succeed but trying to create partition using parted utility gives me error Input/output error during write on /dev/sde.Please help me out to solve these problem.

Comment: Is the attached disk a physical one or a virtual one?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a physical disk, either it's failing or mounted read-only. If it's a virtual disk, it's most likely read-only.

Comment: yes its a virtual disk.if we do fdisk -l it showing me the output as Disk /dev/sdc: 20.0 GB, 20006830080 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2432 cylinders, total 39075840 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table and if we do ls -l output is 
sureline@surestor:~$ ls -l /dev/sdc
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 Apr 29 11:39 /dev/sdc

Comment: You're getting a write failure on `/dev/sde`, but you're also getting `Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table`. Where is the virtual disk located?(what main partition?)

Comment: It was a typo mistake the disk name is /dev/sdc and i am going to partition this disk /dev/sdc and fdisk shows Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table